# RabbitHandler: How to catch "ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'no match' threw exception" correctly and proceed working

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

For an application I am doing some tests with Spring Boot and RabbitMQ.
I set up a very simple Sender - Receiver application:
Sender:

```
public class Tut1Sender
{
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private Queue queue;

    public static int count = 1;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 500)
    public void send() throws InterruptedException
    {
        String message = "Hello World! "+" Nr. "+count;
        MessageObject mo = new MessageObject(message);
        String toJson = gson.toJson(mo);
        this.template.convertAndSend(queue.getName(), toJson);
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + toJson + "'");
        Thread.sleep(5);
        count++;
    }
}
```

This part works just fine and fill my queue with messages.

Here is my receiver:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "hello")
public class Tut1Receiver
{

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @RabbitHandler
    public void receive(String in) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Received Raw: " + in);
        MessageObject fromJson = gson.fromJson(in, MessageObject.class);

        System.out.println("Received Message '" + fromJson + "'");
        int nextInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 5000);
        System.out.println("Sleep for " + nextInt + " ms");
        Thread.sleep(nextInt);
    }
}
```

Messages created by the Sender are handled correctly by the receiver. I get a nice output, the message is acknowledged and deleted from the queue.

Then I put a message directly into the queue by the Web-GUI of RabbitMQ.

The sender grabs this message. I can say this because the message created by me switched from status "Ready" to "Unacked" (as displayed in Web-GUI)
The sender gave me no output.

Then I configured the ContainerFactory:

```
@Profile("receiver")
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(e -> {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e);
            System.out.println("Raw: "+((ListenerExecutionFailedException) e).getFailedMessage().toString());

        });
        return factory;
    }
```

Now I am getting the following error (in an endless loop)

```
Error: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'no match' threw exception
Raw: (Body:'[B@53452feb(byte[11])' MessageProperties [headers={content_type=text/plain, content_encoding=UTF-8}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=true, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=hello, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=NOT_SET, consumerQueue=hello])
```

How can I handle this error? The sender should just display the error, acknowledging the message and proceed with the next message.

What is the right way to handle faulty messages in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For broken message, consumers can `reject` or `deliver` the message. If you are sure the broken message can't be processed by any other consumers, you should tell the broker to discard the message or deliver it to a dead-letter-exchange.

From [official document of spring amqp](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.0.RC1/reference/html/amqp.html#async-listeners), I find:

> Another alternative is to set the container's rejectRequeued property to false. This causes all failed messages to be discarded. When using RabbitMQ 2.8.x or higher, this also facilitates delivering the message to a Dead Letter Exchange.
>
> Or, you can throw a AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException; this prevents message requeuing, regardless of the setting of the rejectRequeued property.